# App crashes after upgrading expo from 35 to 36

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I updated my expo SDK from 35 to 36. Android build does not work on android x versions. The application gives error after splash screen. "Application keeps stopping". and no error.

While I am on the development mode my expo app works fine but once I build it crashes. I am also using sentry for capturing my errors but it seems my app is not loading so sentry can send me error logs.

```
02-04 23:32:34.473 32154 32154 E camy.com.aait: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
02-04 23:32:35.756 32154 32180 E Fabric  : Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/camy.com.aait/settings
02-04 23:32:35.765 32154 32189 E Answers : Failed to retrieve settings
02-04 23:32:36.072  4149  5495 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 7
02-04 23:32:36.092  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 7, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:32:39.347  5494  5494 E ProActiveLaunch: Sending Broadcast
02-04 23:32:39.354  3832  4114 E ActivityManager: TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
02-04 23:32:39.857  3473  3582 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
02-04 23:32:39.961  3314  3335 E BufferQueueProducer: [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity[5494]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:32:39.971  3832  4143 E WindowManager: win=Window{f91f326 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2752 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2450 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayoutForTranslate:302 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:518 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransact:739 <bottom of call stack> 
02-04 23:32:39.990  3832  3928 E WindowManager: win=Window{88aa5e9 u0 Splash Screen camy.com.aait EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:870 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:851 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5406 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:319 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:5828 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:97 
02-04 23:32:40.124 32154 32154 E c       : java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
02-04 23:32:40.757 32154 32248 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0,l(r(d[16])).default)().apiUrl')
02-04 23:32:40.759 32154 32248 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
02-04 23:32:40.759 32154 32248 E ReactNativeJS: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
02-04 23:32:40.759 32154 32248 E ReactNativeJS: * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: Process: camy.com.aait, PID: 32154
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0,l(r(d[16])).default)().apiUrl'), stack:
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@844:329
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@685:240
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@684:137
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@659:251
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@6:82
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: d@2:876
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: global code@1453:4
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime: 
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at host.exp.exponent.experience.a$b.run(BaseExperienceActivity.java:7)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
02-04 23:32:40.765 32154 32154 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
02-04 23:32:40.934 32278 32278 E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
02-04 23:32:40.937 32278 32278 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 1
02-04 23:32:40.945 32278 32278 E oid.sm.provide: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
02-04 23:32:41.019  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1400 audit(1580830361.017:36741): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=32278 comm="oid.sm.provider" name="com.samsung.android.lool-WIDCUtGRZgs05T4sJGE9HQ==" dev="dm-1" ino=657597 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G950F_9_0013 audit_filtered
02-04 23:32:41.019  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1300 audit(1580830361.017:36741): arch=c00000b7 syscall=48 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=770edff780 a2=2 a3=0 items=0 ppid=3450 pid=32278 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="oid.sm.provider" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:system_app:s0 key=(null)
02-04 23:32:41.019  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1327 audit(1580830361.017:36741): proctitle="com.samsung.android.sm.provider"
02-04 23:32:41.020  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1400 audit(1580830361.017:36742): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=32278 comm="oid.sm.provider" name="com.samsung.android.lool-WIDCUtGRZgs05T4sJGE9HQ==" dev="dm-1" ino=657597 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:apk_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G950F_9_0013 audit_filtered
02-04 23:32:41.020  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1300 audit(1580830361.017:36742): arch=c00000b7 syscall=56 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=770ec230a0 a2=42 a3=1a4 items=0 ppid=3450 pid=32278 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="oid.sm.provider" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:system_app:s0 key=(null)
02-04 23:32:41.020  3422  3422 E audit   : type=1327 audit(1580830361.017:36742): proctitle="com.samsung.android.sm.provider"
02-04 23:32:41.369  3314  3335 E Layer   : $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
02-04 23:32:41.369  3314  3335 E Layer   : Abnormal Layer [Screenshot Parent]
02-04 23:32:41.369 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.390 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.390  3314  3335 E Layer   : $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
02-04 23:32:41.390  3314  3335 E Layer   : Abnormal Layer [Screenshot Parent]
02-04 23:32:41.392 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.407 30730 30766 E PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[135153550075097661] not persisted.
02-04 23:32:41.615 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.628 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.795 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:41.805 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:42.142  3832  4338 E Watchdog: !@Sync 10233 [2020-02-04 23:32:42.142] FD count : 604
02-04 23:32:42.188 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:42.190 29931 32270 E FasUtils: pkg=null userId=0 has no information
02-04 23:32:43.688  3832  4143 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 31441 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:32:44.876  3314  3334 E BufferQueueProducer: [Application Error: camy.com.aait#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:32:44.879  3832  4477 E KioskModeService: There's no matched data
02-04 23:32:44.936  3832  3857 E ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
02-04 23:32:46.684  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 7, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:32:47.433  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 32030 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:32:48.202  4149  5495 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 7
02-04 23:32:48.216  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 7, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:00.085  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 18375 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:00.093  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27951 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:00.097  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 28006 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:00.106  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 28027 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:00.113  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 30019 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:00.120  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 30659 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:03.265  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 7, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:04.769  4149  5495 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 7
02-04 23:33:04.790  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 7, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:05.810  3832  5448 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27590 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:12.159  3832  4338 E Watchdog: !@Sync 10234 [2020-02-04 23:33:12.158] FD count : 590
02-04 23:33:14.964  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: updateFingerprintListeningState#mFingerprintRunningState=0 shouldListenForFingerprint=true
02-04 23:33:14.973  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: startListeningForFingerprint() 327
02-04 23:33:15.258  3296  3296 E Sensors : inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(31)
02-04 23:33:15.276  3314  6156 E BufferQueueProducer: [ColorFade#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:33:15.351  3296  3296 E Sensors : inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(31)
02-04 23:33:15.353  3296  3296 E Sensors : inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(31)
02-04 23:33:15.357  3296  3296 E Sensors : inject_scontext_data: New ssp_data_injection_fd(31)
02-04 23:33:15.361  3832  4575 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.503  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.517  3314  3996 E BufferQueueProducer: [com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice.CocktailBarService[9424]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:33:15.521  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: updateFingerprintListeningState#mFingerprintRunningState=1 shouldListenForFingerprint=true
02-04 23:33:15.524  3832  4143 E WindowManager: win=Window{fe4981f u0 com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice.CocktailBarService} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2752 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2450 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayoutForTranslate:302 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:518 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransact:739 <bottom of call stack> 
02-04 23:33:15.539  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.543  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.637  1822  1822 E AbsSettings: refreshInner: refreshedSettingsDBItem key aod_rotation_value val = 5
02-04 23:33:15.657  1822  1822 E AOD_CONFIG@AODConfigurationController: Skipping initialize MONITOR_BATTERY - no registered monitor
02-04 23:33:15.692  3832  3832 E PocketModeEvent: ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
02-04 23:33:15.713  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) pImpl->serverName : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.713  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn : 0x76d30b7e40 
02-04 23:33:15.713  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn->getInterfaceDescriptor() : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.716  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) pImpl->serverName : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.716  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn : 0x76d30b7e40 
02-04 23:33:15.716  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn->getInterfaceDescriptor() : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.719  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) pImpl->serverName : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.719  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn : 0x76d30b7e40 
02-04 23:33:15.719  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn->getInterfaceDescriptor() : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.719  3314  6156 E BufferQueueProducer: [StatusBar[1822]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:33:15.721  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) pImpl->serverName : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.721  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn : 0x76d30b7e40 
02-04 23:33:15.721  3832  4075 E TZ: client_server_communication: comm_request(0x76d417bf80) <IClientServer>pImpl->sconn->getInterfaceDescriptor() : CCM 
02-04 23:33:15.744  3301  3301 E SecHAL  : nfc_hal_write: [Cmd]Send EVT data_sending_flag = true, return size=4!!
02-04 23:33:15.772  3301  6132 E SecHAL  : nfc_data_callback: [Cmd]Received a response packet : data_sending_flag = false!!
02-04 23:33:15.773  4501  6081 E libnfc_nci: [ERROR:nfa_dm_discover.cc(2692)] state: DISCOVERY (1), event: DEACTIVATE_CMD(6) disc_flags: 0x2
02-04 23:33:15.774  3301  3301 E SecHAL  : nfc_hal_write: [Cmd]Send EVT data_sending_flag = true, return size=4!!
02-04 23:33:15.777  3832  5598 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.777  3301  6132 E SecHAL  : nfc_data_callback: [Cmd]Received a response packet : data_sending_flag = false!!
02-04 23:33:15.778  4501  6081 E libnfc_nci: [ERROR:nfc_ncif.cc(1152)] nfc_ncif_proc_deactivate - evt_data.deactivate.reason 246, nfc_cb.deact_reason = 0
02-04 23:33:15.779  4501  6081 E libnfc_nci: [ERROR:nfa_dm_discover.cc(2692)] state: DISCOVERY (1), event: DEACTIVATE_RSP(7) disc_flags: 0x22
02-04 23:33:15.780  3301  3301 E SecHAL  : nfc_hal_write: [Cmd]Send EVT data_sending_flag = true, return size=7!!
02-04 23:33:15.781  3301  6132 E SecHAL  : nfc_data_callback: [Cmd]Received a response packet : data_sending_flag = false!!
02-04 23:33:15.781  3301  3301 E SecHAL  : nfc_hal_write: [Cmd]Send EVT data_sending_flag = true, return size=a!!
02-04 23:33:15.784  3301  6132 E SecHAL  : nfc_data_callback: [Cmd]Received a response packet : data_sending_flag = false!!
02-04 23:33:15.784  4501  6081 E libnfc_nci: [ERROR:nfa_dm_discover.cc(2692)] state: IDLE (0), event: DISCOVER_RSP(1) disc_flags: 0x31
02-04 23:33:15.785  4149  4160 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 8
02-04 23:33:15.807  3314  3996 E BufferQueueProducer: [NavigationBar[1822]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:33:15.807  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: android.uid.bcmgr, scannerId: 8, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:15.811  3832  4575 E WindowManager: win=Window{27dd8e3 u0 NavigationBar} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2752 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2450 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayoutForTranslate:302 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:518 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransact:739 <bottom of call stack> 
02-04 23:33:15.822  4149  4160 E BtGatt.ContextMap: remove() - removed: 6
02-04 23:33:15.825  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: com.google.uid.shared, scannerId: 6, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:15.827  3832  5598 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:15.828  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: updateFingerprintListeningState#mFingerprintRunningState=1 shouldListenForFingerprint=true
02-04 23:33:15.894  4149  4665 E BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: android.uid.bcmgr, scannerId: 6, reportDelayMillis=0
02-04 23:33:15.907  4149  4661 E BtGatt.ScanManager: default value of curScanSetting 0 is choosen
02-04 23:33:20.014  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.032  3314  6156 E BufferQueueProducer: [com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity[5494]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
02-04 23:33:20.051  3832  4143 E WindowManager: win=Window{f91f326 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2752 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2450 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayoutForTranslate:302 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:518 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:186 android.os.Binder.execTransact:739 <bottom of call stack> 
02-04 23:33:20.305  3832  5598 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.349  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.358  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.390  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: updateFingerprintListeningState#mFingerprintRunningState=1 shouldListenForFingerprint=true
02-04 23:33:20.393  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.419  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:20.485  1822  1822 E KeyguardFingerPrint: updateFingerprintListeningState#mFingerprintRunningState=1 shouldListenForFingerprint=true
02-04 23:33:20.539  3832  4143 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 23:33:35.146  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 30977 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:35.151  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 31087 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:39.858  3473  3582 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
02-04 23:33:42.179  3832  4338 E Watchdog: !@Sync 10235 [2020-02-04 23:33:42.178] FD count : 586
02-04 23:33:45.939  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 18375 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:45.944  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 27951 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:45.949  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 28006 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:45.955  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 28027 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:45.961  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 30019 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:45.984  3832  5598 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 31441 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:33:47.325 32349 32349 E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
02-04 23:33:47.328 32349 32349 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 1
02-04 23:33:47.352 32349 32349 E ickSettingsTil: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
02-04 23:33:57.817  3832  5488 E BartenderActivityManager: BarTender: pid : 30659 cached=true abnormal=false kill=false stay=false release=false
02-04 23:34:12.199  3832  4338 E Watchdog: !@Sync 10236 [2020-02-04 23:34:12.199] FD count : 586
0
```

Comment: Can you get the crash log through logcat?

Comment: @CampbellMG how can I use logcat on production app. as far as I know it works on app during development mode

Comment: Logcat is available on any android phone and not necessarily bound to an app. Just plug your phone in and run `adb logcat`

Comment: @CampbellMG I've updated the question with logcat on production app

Comment: This: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0,l(r(d[16])).default)().apiUrl')` is your crash. Is this code from your app?

Comment: @CampbellMG Thank you very much. the problem was with the apiurl definition. I fixed it now it works on the production too